# How to set the parameter for image data type for an image in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hi everyone as I am new in flutter having problem to set image data type.
 I have two boxes where  I need to drag one and fit on to other box (auto fit). But I am facing an error in declaring my image parameter.I am able to drag an item box with an image but the dragged item is not accepted by the dragTarget object existing within.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code and screenshot:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Episode3 extends StatelessWidget {
  var accpeptedData = Image.asset("");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          DraggableWidget(
            offset: Offset(50.0, 80.0),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 100.0,
            left: 100.0,
            child: DragTarget(
              builder: (BuildContext context, List<dynamic> accepted,
                      List<dynamic> rejected) =>
                  Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 200.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Image.file(accpeptedData.toString()),
                    ),
                  ),
              onAccept: (Image data) {
                accpeptedData = data;
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DraggableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Offset offset;

  DraggableWidget({Key key, this.offset}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DraggableWidgetState createState() => _DraggableWidgetState();
}
class _DraggableWidgetState extends State<DraggableWidget> {
  Offset offset = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    offset = widget.offset;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      bottom: offset.dy,
      left: offset.dx,
      child: Draggable(
        data: Image.asset("ss/camera-icon.png"),
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(
            child: Image.asset("ss/camera-icon.png")
          ),
        ),
        feedback: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
          child: Center(
            child: Image.asset("ss/camera-icon.png")
          ),
        ),
        onDraggableCanceled: (v, o) {`enter code here`
          setState(() {
            offset = o;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a clarification, the code you've provided above runs even if there is an error in line 25 as stated in your screenshot? Or this is a new implementation and causes you an error in that line? Could you provide the error message? Also I found [this blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/drag-and-drop-ui-elements-in-flutter-with-draggable-and-dragtarget/) helpful. If this is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Image.file()` needs a File object. The reason why an error appears here is because a String is passed instead of a File. What you can do here is parse the String file path.

```dart
Image.file(File(accpeptedData.toString()))
```